# Sharing Data between two controllers

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular 1.x and I am trying to share data from one controller to another

I am using the above model in mainctrl. The radiotmplt.radiohead=='IRU600v3'is from firstctrl. I cannot share data using rootscope. Please advise.

Comment: service will be the best practice for sharing data between the controllers.

Comment: Surely a search in SO finds plenty of results like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: Is it parent and child relationship?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo how to share data using RootScope

link [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu936fr5/)

**Js**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.data = 'data';
    $rootScope.data1 = 'old data';
    $scope.setVal = function() {
      $rootScope.data1 = 'new data';
    }
  });

  app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.data = $rootScope.data1;
    $scope.$watch('data1', function(o, n) {

      $scope.data = $rootScope.data1;

    })
  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
      controller 1
      <input type='text' ng-model='data'>
      <button ng-click='setVal()'>
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>
      controller 2
      <input type='text' ng-model='data'>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Best way to use service or factory or $broadcast  for this kind data sharing